# Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

I am a newbie to react and lot of struggle getting started, this may be a simple problem but I couldnt find an answer in google or whatever. I was trying to run a git code from a youtube channel - lama dev from sep - 2021. Is that an issue due to the changes in node since that period? My react app in not getting started due to this

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:488
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports" in E:\E-com Project\ver-one-zero-one\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\node_modules\postcss\package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:439:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:718:3)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\E-com Project\ver-one-zero-one\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\lib\safe-parser.js:1:17) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}

Node.js v17.7.2
```

Comment: on searching at the left end (explorer of vs code) I couldn't find any result for ./lib or lib or .lib etc? what would that be? @DeanJames

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried updating the node modules with

```
npm update
```

and the issue was solved. I am keeping it here so that someone else can find the answer if they are looking for

Answer (score 1):

You should add "./lib/tokenize.js" to the exports entry of package.json so you can import it.